# Form with two submit buttons with different actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

so I have a form that has 3 buttons

```
        <td >
            <input type="submit" id="stSave" class="button button_save pointer" value=""/>
            <input type="submit"  id="stSaveReturn" class="button button_save_return pointer" value=""/>
            <button id="stCancel" class="button button_cancel pointer simplemodal-close"></button>
        </td>
```

When I click save. It saves and the modal stays open. great

When i hit cancel it closes. great

however I can't figure out how to go about Making it so when i click save and return it will submit the form and then close the modal. I tried to add an onclick() event but that triggers before the submit it seems.

Here is what my form deceleration looks like.

```
<form:form method="post" action="${CTX_PATH}/admin/statepost" commandName="detailsDto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Is this form in an iframe on your modal?

Comment: you can listen to `submit` event. But for a clean approach, use a simple button, not a submit button and listen to its click events. Based on the clicked button, do your action.

Comment: I might be tempted to turn the stSaveReturn into just a normal type="button" and handle the submit and close logically in the click handler for it.

Comment: @Scoots  Yes, It is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to listen to the submit event of your `stSaveReturn` input.

For example:

```
$('#stSaveReturn').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the form submit event and perform a modal close. If you are concerned the `iframe` may be destroyed before the submit actually happens, you can delay the modal close with a `setTimeout()` call (although this feels overcomplicated).

See sample code below:

```js
//using jquery
$('#whatever_is_your_form_id').on('submit', function(event){
  if(event.target.id === 'stSaveReturn'){
    //either do immediate modal close
    $('#modal_element_id').modal('hide');
    //or delay the modal close for 50millisecs or more
    setTimeout(function closeModal(){
      $('#modal_element_id').modal('hide');
    }, 50); //close after 50ms
  }
});
```

```html
<td >
    <input type="submit" id="stSave" class="button button_save pointer" value=""/>
    <input type="submit"  id="stSaveReturn" class="button button_save_return pointer" value=""/>
    <button id="stCancel" class="button button_cancel pointer simplemodal-close"></button>
</td>
```

Comment: This does not seem to get hit      if(event.target.id === 'stSaveReturn')       I tested with console.log and the on submit part gets hit but not the event target id being stSaveReturn

Comment: so I dont know why but i tried doing it just as an on click event for the stSaveTReturn button to close the modal and it seems to be working fine.. I swear I tried it yesterday but looking at your code to me it seemed to just be doing the same thing in a round about way. Not sure why it works now. Maybe I was tired yesterday. thanks